Roslyn Analyzer should use more than one code file at once
I am writing some Roslyn Analyzers at the moment and some of them have to use information from several classes (usualy located in different files) in order to fullfill their job.
For example, I need an analyzer, that checks if a class implements an interface. If that's the case the analyzer searchs for the "HandleAsync" Method and checks the return type. The return type is supposed to be generic, if that is the case, the analyzer tries to check, if the generic class (e.g. T for ValueTask) has a specific attribute.
I've tried different approaches, but the result is always the same: it works in my tests, because the classes are in the same file there. In the real application, the analyzer does not work.
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
    context.ConfigureGeneratedCodeAnalysis(GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.None);
    context.EnableConcurrentExecution();
    context.RegisterCompilationAction(CheckForGenericReturnType);
}

private void CheckForGenericReturnType(CompilationAnalysisContext context)
{
    var compilation = context.Compilation;
    foreach (var syntaxTree in compilation.SyntaxTrees) 
    { 
        var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(syntaxTree);

        var root = syntaxTree.GetRoot();
        var classDeclarations = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>();

        foreach (var classDeclaration in classDeclarations)
        {
            var classSymbol = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(classDeclaration) as INamedTypeSymbol;

            var name = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(classDeclaration).BaseType.Name;

            if (!name.Equals("SomeInterface"))
            {
                continue;
            }

            var methodSymbol = classSymbol.GetMembers().OfType<IMethodSymbol>().FirstOrDefault(method => method.Name == "HandleAsync");

            if (methodSymbol == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            var returnType = methodSymbol.ReturnType;

            if (returnType != null)
            {
                if (returnType is INamedTypeSymbol namedTypeSymbol && namedTypeSymbol.IsGenericType)
                {
                    var genericClassName = namedTypeSymbol.TypeArguments.FirstOrDefault();

                    if (genericClassName != null)
                    {
                        // search for classDefinition of the generic class, than check if attribute exists.
                        CheckForGenericClass(context, genericClassName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}

private void CheckForGenericClass(CompilationAnalysisContext context, ITypeSymbol className)
{
    var compilation = context.Compilation;
    foreach (var syntaxTree in compilation.SyntaxTrees)
    {
        var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(syntaxTree);

        var root = syntaxTree.GetRoot();
        var classDeclarations = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>();

        foreach (var classDeclaration in classDeclarations)
        {
            var classSymbol = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(classDeclaration) as INamedTypeSymbol;

            var name = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(classDeclaration).Name;

            if (!name.Equals(className.Name))
            {
                continue;
            }

            var hasAttribute = classSymbol.GetAttributes().Any(attribute => attribute.AttributeClass.Name == "TestAttribute");

            if (!hasAttribute)
            {
                var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, classSymbol.Locations[0], classSymbol.Name);
                context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}

Added unit Test:
using Xunit;
using Some.Namespace.ExampleImportedName;
using Verify = Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Testing.CSharpAnalyzerVerifier<
    NH.Analyzers.QueryHandlerRule,
    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Testing.DefaultVerifier>;

namespace NH.Analyzers.Test
{
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Fact]
        public async void CorrectImplementation()
        {

            var text = @"
using Some.Namespace.ExampleImportedName;

[QueryHandler]
internal sealed class SomeExampleClass : SomeInterface<ClassA>
{
    private readonly ImportedBuilderClass _builder;

    public SomeExampleClass(RepositoryClass repositoryClass)
    {
        _builder = new ImportedBuilderClass(repositoryClass);
    }

    
    public async ValueTask<genericClass> HandleAsync(ClassC classC)
    {
        DoSomething(classC);

        return someClass;
    }
}
";

            await Verify.VerifyAnalyzerAsync(text);

        }
    }
}

As described in a comment bellow, I get the following error in all of my different unitTests for classes/namespaces I import from other projects from my solutionn:
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ExampleImportedName' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Some' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)


I think you just need to check attributes in genericClassName.GetAttributes().

That's exactly what I did in the past. But it seemed like Roslyn just knew the name of the genericClass, but nothing else, except if the other class was specified in the same file.
Maybe I have a problem on how to test it with several files as well. Bc. when I run my unit tests I always get errors, that types and namespaces can't be found

Can you share your unit tests? That might be the problem there that they're not setting up the environment right for actually running the tests. A common problem is if the references aren't right, then the compiler doesn't have useful semantics; it might kinda work in a single file case if you get lucky though.

@JasonMalinowski added an example for one of my unit tests (it is supposed to verify, that no diagnostic occurs, but instead a lot of the mentioned errors do occur)

The problem here is that RegisterCompilationAction is for syntax analysis, and you need to register an action for semantic analysis (such as RegisterSyntaxNodeAction) to get the real symbol.
For example:
context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(CheckForGenericReturnType,
                                 SyntaxKind.MethodDeclaration);

This will register the action to be executed for each method declaration, you can obtain a IMethodSymbol from the context, and then you can check its name, interfaces, etc.
private void CheckForGenericReturnType(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
    var symbol = context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(context.Node);

    if (symbol is IMethodSymbol methodSymbol &&

        symbol.Name == "HandleAsync" &&

        symbol.ContainingType.Interfaces.Any(i => i.Name == "SomeInterface") &&

        methodSymbol.ReturnType is INamedTypeSymbol namedReturnType &&

        namedReturnType.IsGenericType &&

        namedReturnType.TypeArguments.First()
                       .GetAttributes().First()
                       .AttributeClass.Name == "TestAttribute"
        ...


Thanks for the answer.
I acutally had already tried this out, as well as using context.RegisterSemanticModelAction and bc I had the same issue as described above I changed to Compilation, because I thought maybe the analyzer knew more than, and not just about one class or one method.
I have another problem:
If I test my analyzers, I always get more errors/diagnostics than expected, because I get a ton of "error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ExampleImportedName' could not be found ..."
Maybe this is the reason, why my analyzers don't behave the why I would like them to?

Even if this doesn't fix the problem, this will make things a lot friendlier for performance -- your original analyzer code that's grabbing all trees and analyzing all files might slow the IDE down since we can't optimize you to be analyzing the file the user is editing, for example.

@Baumeister28 I don't know what ExampleImportedName is, you may test with a single analyzer.

This is just a namespace of mine. It is from another project in the same solution and I have added it to the project and imported it (using ExampleImportedName)
@JasonMalinowski that makes sense, I will go back to this solution and try to fix the other issue.

You should open a new question for this. Simply put, if the code you want to verify needs to reference another assembly, you need to create a CSharpAnalyzerTest object and config its ReferenceAssemblies property.
